# Refresh page content after form submission

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a PHP file that generates a JQuery-Mobile page using SQL-Queries:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
[...]
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
[... a listview and a form ...]
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="page2">
[... some stuff ...]
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The form has the same PHP file as action that generates the whole page. So, JQuery Mobile will submit the request to this file and refresh the page content (at least theoretically).

When submitting one of these forms, the content of the page get's updated. But after switching between the pages, the new content is lost.

I already tried to disable caching, but this did not work.
Also I read the documentation of jquerymobile, but I do not really understand how this ajax submission works. What should my PHP file return in case of an submission? The entire site?

Cheers

Comment: This also happens if I put `data-ajax=”false”` in all form/a tags...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would keep the form action outside the first file so that code is seperate.  You could then submit the form using ajax and make the form action return some sort of JSON data to indicate whether the submit was successful (something like `{code : 200, message : "Success"}` should do)

Comment: And then add the new content dynamically with javascript? Sounds good. But changes made by other users will not be included. Maybe, I should return the whole new content in JSON format and add it to the page.

Comment: @user2177347 by other users do you mean other developers? if they want they can change the message text. it would then show up on your screen.